# security alert: problems with certificate

Tags: actionscript-3, https, air

Suppose an AIR application. I upload file to file storage with FileReference.upload(...). The problem is that all's fine on our server, but there's security alert on customer's server: "the certificate you are viewing does not match the name of the site you are trying to view". Here's a snap-shot:

[image]

Does anyone can prompt me where the problem is? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Alert from html page or SecurityException?

Comment: @alxx , I've just added a snap-shot

Comment: You can view certificate and check if its name matches customer server's name. If not, it's their problem (quite common one.) You can't bypass it by means of Flash.

Comment: @alxx, the problem is that I should work via http://. So it's https:// somewhere...

Comment: Use Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) to sniff traffic from the client, with the HTTPS decryption option turned on. Fiddler will tell you exactly what the URL is, and what certificate the site is trying to send.